# Shorthand to check value in array

Tags: php, arrays, compare

Is there a short way of doing this?

```
if ((isset($a['key']) && ($a['key'] == 'value')) {
  echo 'equal';
  // more code
}
else {
  echo 'not equal';
  // more code
}
```

I need to test lots of values on an array that can or cannot exist. I feel that this method is too verbose.

I could remove the `isset()` and mute the notices... but then I feel dirty.

**Edit:**

Answering Jack's question: *"Could you give an example how you would test lots of values in an array?"*

example:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'view') {
  //code
}
if (isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] == 'name') {
  //code
}
if (isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'up') {
  //code
}
if (isset($_GET['tag']) && $_GET['tag'] == 'sometag') {
  //code
}
etc...
```

Comment: Imagine that there's more code inside. What I want to make shorter is the part inside the "if ()".

Comment: The only shorter expression is one without the redundant parentheses :)

Comment: it is not that long or unreadable. this micro optimisation will lead you no where.

Comment: As it stands now, you shouldn't receive warnings from the interpreter (provided you remove that stray `(`). Are you?

Comment: Could you give an example how you would test lots of values in an array?

Comment: The best approach is to use a function. I don't see a reason not to use a function like "function isEqual($array, $key, $value){ //your condition}" or better practice in OOP to have a class that contains the array and that way you don't have to pass the array each time

Comment: Thanks for the example, updated my answer with something else to consider.

Comment: You can do that by a foreach loop. Would you like to have an insight of that ? Let me know if you are. I will write a demo for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like to answer my own questions but I feel that the best and cleaner way to do this kind of checkings is to write a "helper funcion" like:

```
function iskeyval(&$a, $k, $v) {
  return isset($a['key']) && ($a['key'] == 'value');
}
```

and then:

```
if (iskeyval($a, 'key', 'value')) {
  ...
}
else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can always write a function around something, but afaict the question was whether the expression could be made shorter and it can't :) btw, you can use `(array $a, $k, $v)` as the argument list instead to let PHP check the argument type for you.

Answer (score 9):

*For anyone still stumbling upon this question...*

You could use [PHP's coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```php
if (($a['key'] ?? '') === 'value') {
  echo 'equal';
  // more code
}
else {
  echo 'not equal';
  // more code
}
```

See this question: [using PHP's null coalescing operator on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342617/using-phps-null-coalescing-operator-on-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments to explain the code. Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/4061240) :

```
//this array maps the function with the get parameters
$functions = array (
"action" => "do_actions" ,
"filter" => "do_filters"
);


foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
    //check if this field is corresponding functions or not  
    if ( array_key_exists($key , $functions) ) {
        call_user_func($functions[$key] , $key,$value);
    }
}


function do_actions ($key , $value) {
    //place your code here to play with this value
    echo 'do_actions is called with ' . $key . 'and' . $value . "</br>";
}

function do_filters ($key , $value) {
    //place your code here to play with this value
    echo 'do_filters is called with ' . $key . ' and ' . $value .  "</br>";
}


?>
```

Comment: I don't want to execute a function for *Every* GET varibale.

Comment: Ah,sure . This is just a way of achieving the same result. One of the benefits i got this approach is it increases readability IMO.

Answer (score -2):

```
$list = array(
0 => 'one',
1 => 'two',
2 => 'one',
3 => 'three',
4 => 'one',
);

if( @$list['xxx'] !== 'three')
    echo 'Not ';


echo 'Equal';
```

Suppress the error reporting.

Comment: Do not try this at home kids.