# using PHP's null coalescing operator on an array

Tags: php, arrays, ternary

I am using PHP's null coalescing operator described by http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php.

```
Null coalescing operator ¶
The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

<?php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
?>
```

I noticed the following doesn't produce my expected results which was to add a new `phone` index to `$params` whose value is "default".

```
$params=['address'=>'123 main street'];
$params['phone']??'default';
```

Why not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't add anything to params. Your given code simply generates an unused return value:

```
$params['phone'] ?? 'default'; // returns phone number or "default", but is unused
```

Thus, you will still have to set it:

```
$params['phone'] = $params['phone'] ?? 'default';
```

Answer (score 15):

The correct answer above from [@mrks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2204581/mrks) can be shortened to:

```
    $params['phone'] ??= 'default';
```

[RFC: Null coalesce equal operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator)